# Why does matplotlib have so many options for 'making' a plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

So I have been using matplot for a while now, and one thing that confuses me how it handles subplots.

It can be done as such:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,2,1)
```

Or. It could be done as such:

```
plt.subplots(1,2)
```

Or, one could do this instead:

```
plt.subplot(211)
```

Or of course, if we only need one plot we can immediately run

```
plt.plot(x,y) # or .scatter or whatever.
```

Why? Is there any actual reason why you should use one over the others?

Comment: The simple API provides convenience and simplicity that is perfectly fine for simple use cases. The object-oriented API provides more control and extendability to writers of more complex and modular visualisation code. For further reading: https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/lifecycle.html

Comment: It's a bit hard to know how an answer to this should look like. Of course everyone can provide an enumeration of use cases where they would use one or the other - which is to be avoided and questions that trigger such answers would be closed as "primarily opinion-based". I can tell you though that there was some effort on the matplotlib documentation to use ´fig, ax = plt.subplots()` throughout, except for the pure pyplot examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Matplotlib is a Python library, that was significantly influenced by MatLab and aimed in part at former and current MatLab users, therefore has 2 types of syntax:

- MatLab syntax, `plt.sublot(211); plt.plot(); plt.colorbar();`, that implies that every time you create a figure or subplot it is stored inside as last active object and all plotting and changing of parameters is applied to it. It is to make it comfortable to use for those, who transitioned from MatLab. The idea is you create an element and instantly apply all actions to it, then create next and never return to previous until you call `plt.show` .
- Classic programming syntax with explicit object declaration and operations on said objects. It is comfortable for everyone else and allows one to go back to previously created objects (figures and axes) and make additional changes.

The matlab way makes it hard to work with multiple figures. (figure is an independent picture, axes is region of that picture that you plot data in) plt.show always shows the last figure you created, example:

```
plt.figure() #new figure created and stored as current active
Plt.subplot() #new axes created in current figure and stored as current axes
Plt.plot() #data plotted in current axes
Plt.subplot() #second axes added to figure and made current active
Plt.plot() #plot in current active that is second now
Plt.figure() #the new figure created, old can still be found with difficulty i believe,
#but current active is now different and plt.show will not show anything you plotted before.
```

But some people find it better for quick and dirty plotting.

You can transition between the 2 by using `fig_1 = plt.gcf();`, `ax_1 = plt.gca();` which are get current figure and get current axes redpectively. There are also multiple ways to change appearance, one for matlab

```
plt.make_current_axes_without_ticks( param)
```

and one for oop languages (

```
fig=plt.figure;
ax=fig.add_axes();
axis=ax.y_axis();
yticks=axis.ticks();
yticks.set_visible(false);
```

or smth like that.

Multiple interfaces sure make learning it harder, but it makes easier to transition from other similar tools and make it less rigid, meaning sometimes there're very simple ways to make frequently used but convoluted changes. (See ticks example)